# how to get and set array inside the ADO pipeline Powershell from variable?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have below code in **yaml** file:

```
trigger:
   branches:
        include: 
        - maventest
pool:

  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    filePath: './1.ps1'
```

Below is **1.ps1** file

```
$user1=@($(user))

Write-Host $(user)

write-host $user1[0]
```

As I can pass the value of variable inside while run pipeline but user is not getting from variable.
[image]

I had also used the $(env:user) but it didn't get value from variable.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your YAML sample, the cause of the issue is that the pipeline variable is not able to directly expand in PowerShell file.

To solve this issue, you can pass the pipeline variable to ps file via argument of PowerShell task.

Here is the example:

**Ps file sample:**

```
param($user)
$user1=@($user)

Write-Host $user

write-host $user1[0]
```

**Pipeline sample:**

```
steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    filePath: './1.ps1'
    arguments: '-user $(user)'
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @kevin for taking time to answer the question , you have saved my lot of time.